# Describe the span of the set consisting of these two points in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: linear-algebra

I just started my linear algebra course and I came across this question.

> Describe the span of the set consisting of these two points in
>   $\mathbb R^2:e_1=(1,0),e_2=(0,1)$

Definition of span: Span of a set of vectors is the collection of all linear combinations of vectors in the given set.

Solution in my textbook is given as:
$\alpha  e_1+\beta e_2=a$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    1  \\
    0  \\
    \end{bmatrix}
+\beta \begin{bmatrix}
    0  \\
    1  \\
    \end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}
    \alpha  \\
    \beta  \\
    \end{bmatrix}$

My doubt is why did we write vector $e_1$ as $\begin{bmatrix}
    1  \\
    0  \\
    \end{bmatrix}$(Column matrix) but not $ \begin{bmatrix}1&2\\ \end{bmatrix} $(Row matrix)

Also please give me some more knowledge or tips before starting these concepts.

Comment: It is a convention to use column matrix for the matrix product.

Comment: @Lucas What if its written as $e_1=(1,0)^T$?  I will still use column matrix?

Comment: $e_1 = (1,0)^T$ stands directly for the column matrix, since the T means transposed and it uses up "less space".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the span is $\alpha\begin{bmatrix}
    1  \\
    0  \\
    \end{bmatrix}
+\beta \begin{bmatrix}
    0  \\
    1  \\
    \end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}
    \alpha  \\
    \beta  \\
    \end{bmatrix}$ where $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{R}$ can be chosen arbitrarily, the span will be $\mathbb{R}^2$ itself.

---

Column matrix notation is the one you want to use when also considering matrices, since you usually write matrix vector multiplication like $\begin{bmatrix}
    a & b \\
    c & d \\
    \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
    e  \\
    f  \\
    \end{bmatrix}$. If you don't consider matrices, it doesn't really matter if you represent $e_1$ as column matrix $\begin{bmatrix}
    1  \\
    0  \\
    \end{bmatrix}=(1,0)^T$ or row matrix (actually more like coordinate) $(1,0)$.